# dynamic options in p-multiselect primeng angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to implement datatable of primeng. 
In which, I have **created an array of header, field and options**, i.e.: headersList.

It is as shown below:

```js
{
  header: "Time",
  field: "time",
  options: "timeOptions"
}, {
  header: "Date",
  field: "date",
  options: "dateOptions"
}, {
  header: "Table No.",
  field: "table_no",
  options: "tableOptions"
}
```

I am passing this array to 'p-column' like this:

```html
<p-column *ngFor="let head of headersList" [field]="head.field" [header]="head.header" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="search" filterMatchMode="in">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
    <p-multiSelect [options]="head.options" defaultLabel="Search" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)"></p-multiSelect>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

But it's not working. I need to add **options field of headersList** to **options of p-multiselect**

Comment: What should be in options? An object with settings? If so could you please provide an example of such setting object? Cause now you're passing just a string. Maybe of course you have this setting objects in your controller. Need to see at that code.

Comment: I have added JSON data to the options:                                                       
`this.timeOptions.push({ label: element.appointment_time, value: element.appointment_time });
 this.dateOptions.push({ label: element.appointment_date, value: element.appointment_date });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you are not passing options as array

Here , This field :

```
options: "timeOptions"
```

Should look like

```
options: [
            {label: 'White', value: 'White'},
            {label: 'White1', value: 'White1'}
         ]
```

So, After changes your json should look something like :

```
{
  header: "Time",
  field: "time",
  options: [
            {label: 'White', value: 'White'},
            {label: 'White1', value: 'White1'}
            ]
}, {
  header: "Date",
  field: "date",
  options: [
            {label: 'White', value: 'White'},
            {label: 'White1', value: 'White1'}
            ]
}, {
  header: "Table No.",
  field: "table_no",
  options: [
            {label: 'White', value: 'White'},
            {label: 'White1', value: 'White1'}
            ]
}
```

---

As per the comment on your question , If this is the code you are implementing

```
this.timeOptions.push({
    label: element.appointment_time,
    value: element.appointment_time
});
this.dateOptions.push({
    label: element.appointment_date,
    value: element.appointment_date
});
```

Then

this `options: "timeOptions"` should look like `options: timeOptions` (without double quotes for all options key)

Comment: It is showing an error: **Error trying to diff '{ label: 'White', value: 'White' }'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed**

Comment: Try to use this example with your options. It's just an example.

Comment: @SargamSanghani, issue was coz of same value in select , try now

Comment: Could you please update your question with new code that you changed? We would like to see how you're applying it.

Comment: @SargamSanghani , will you please create a demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: @SargamSanghani, please check updated answer last block

Comment: Thank u for your precious time.. @VivekDoshi